# Can we deploy kony dockers into non Azure cloud, As per my understanding kony only supports dockers for Azure cloud

Tags: temenos-quantum

I am struggling to get the details to understand if kony supported docker images can we published to any non Azure cloud, like AWS and google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Images for all the components that make up Kony Fabric — Kony's API Manager and Middleware — are published to the [Docker Hub under the **konyfabric** account](https://hub.docker.com/u/konyfabric). These images are agnostic to whatever the external container orchestration layer is.

If you look at [this post](https://basecamp.kony.com/s/article-detail/a046A00000AVFL0QAP/fabric-as-a-docker-container) on Kony Base Camp you'll see there is a diagram that shows the additional dependencies for deploying the Kony Platform onto Azure.

[image: Kony Azure Deployment]

Notice that this guide is based on the use of Kubernetes, and the only other things you'd need besides the pods are a load balancer (NGINX in the diagram) and a database. All you'd really need to do in order to deploy to another IaaS vendor is get equivalent services to Azure's Kubernetes Service, Azure SQL DB and an NGINX pod.

Answer (score 0):

As of now Kony Fabric docker container is supported for on-premises and Azure Cloud only. Kony is planning to extend its support to other clouds as well in near future.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not supported. However you can raise it as idea in 
https://basecamp.kony.com/s/ideation?page=1

[article](https://basecamp.kony.com/s/article-detail/a046A00000AVFL0QAP/fabric-as-a-docker-container) mentioned by @Mig82 given an overview of fabric in docker.

You can download Kony Fabric docker from below link along with installation link.
https://community.kony.com/downloads/archive

The prerequisites can be checked from [here](https://basecamp.kony.com/s/question/0D52K00003kBPUgSAO/list-of-prerequites-before-going-for-the-docker-auto-installation). But you may need Kony login to access.